# ubuntu 12.04, xerox workcenter 4118, garbage printing

Tags: 12.04, printing, xerox

I am printing garbage (like *postscript? %!PS-Adobe-3.0 ...*) since I have installed official driver for this printer, but when I install driver for *Xerox WorkCentre 7345 Foomatic/ljet4* it works well BUT it prints everytime **one page more** with only content:"reset".

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to it's specifications this printer supports PCL6 and PCL5e printer language, it can support PostScript with an optional module.

If you have the PostScript module it should be possible to use the PPD file provided by Xerox to get this printer working (recommended), if you don't have that module you can still select one of the Generic PCL6 or PCL5e drivers (other than ljet4) included with Ubuntu.